# How to change colors on plotly 'scattermapbox'

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly

I'm trying to get multiple colors on my scatter map box to show highest to lowest values.

This is what I have tried so far and I dont know what else I can change.

```
cityb<-select(JCCitiBike,"tripduration", "start.station.id", "start.station.name","latitude","longitude", "usertype","gender" )%>% mutate(start=percent_rank(start.station.name))


#filter areas with most traffic identifying them with usertype.

cityb1<- filter(cityb,tripduration>3100)

cityb2 <- cityb  %>% select("tripduration", "start.station.id", "start.station.name","latitude","longitude", "usertype","gender", "start") 

p1 <- cityb1 %>% plot_ly(type = 'scattermapbox', lat = ~latitude, lon = ~longitude, marker = list( size=15, colors='rainbow'),text=~gettextf(start.station.name)) 
p1 <- p1 %>% layout(mapbox = list(style = 'open-street-map', zoom =7, center = list(lon = -74, lat = 41)))
p1
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for. Have you looked at the information that [Plotly provided](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scattermapbox)?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg